# How use 'for-loop' and column addition to produce column in dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I'm quite new to python and so would really appreciate some help.

I've simplified my dataframes as I'm working on large ones.
My question is what would the code be to produce a new column in df1 so that it looks like 'Merged' in df2 - ie it is made up of:

1. the 'Letter' column value
2. a 'for loop' that either includes an underscore and 'Number' value if it exists, or skips this step if there isn't a value (such as the final row)
3. an underscore and 'Capital' column value

```
data1 = {'Letter': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
         'Number': ['1', '2', ''],
         'Capital': ['A', 'B', 'C']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame (data1, columns = ['Letter', 'Number', 'Capital'])
print(df1)



data2 = {'Letter': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
         'Number': ['1', '2', ''],
         'Capital': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
         'Merged': ['a_1_A', 'b_2_B', 'c_C']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame (data2, columns = ['Letter', 'Number', 'Capital', 'Merged'])
print(df2)
```

Sorry, I can't figure out how to run this code but hopefully that makes sense. I understand how to add columns (below) but can't figure out how to incorporate a for loop. My best guess is:

```
df1["merged"] = (df1["Letter"] + 
                     for value in data1:
                         if data1["Number"] != "":
                            "_" + data1["Number"]
                         else:
                + "_" + df1["Capital"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your logic in a separate function and apply this function to each row.
In order to eliminate the empty fields, include filter() method.

```
def func(row):
    row['merged'] = '_'.join(filter(None, row))
    return row

df1 = df1.apply(func, axis=1)
df1
```

Result:

```
  Letter Number Capital merged
0      a      1       A  a_1_A
1      b      2       B  b_2_B
2      c              C    c_C
```

Or, you can just use the lambda function:

```
df1['merged'] = df1.apply(lambda row: '_'.join(filter(None, row)), axis=1)
df1
```

Result:

```
  Letter Number Capital merged
0      a      1       A  a_1_A
1      b      2       B  b_2_B
2      c              C    c_C
```

(Almost always, there is more than one way in Pandas to achieve the same result - which can be both confusing and amazing!)

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Developing further, is there a way to do this but only concatinate specific columns, not an entire row? ie say there was another column "Symbols: '!', '?', ':' " that was in the dataframe that I didn't want to include in the new column?

Comment: Yes. Inside the function (either lambda or a separate method) you can refer to column names. For example, if you only want to include Letter and Number: `df1['merged'] = df1.apply(lambda row: '_'.join(filter(None, [row['Letter'], row['Number']])), axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks, so helpful. I'm now getting results like 'C_nan_C' where columns have no value, instead of C_C. Any ideas why/resolution? For the code to work, I had to convert the dataframe columns' datatype to 'string'. Maybe that's linked...

Comment: Could you share some examples of your data? Are you having `np.NaN` values in your data frame, or is it just a text value 'nan'? Handling this may be problematic as np.NaN does not equal any value (`np.NaN == np.NaN` will return False) and cannot be filtered out like the other values. You may consider processing the empty values before you proceed with the other transformations. I tried to reproduce it but I get an error instead of 'nan' inside the merged column so I am not sure what is causing your problem.